# How to get Raphael element by data or any other unique value?

Tags: jquery, raphael

I made 2 circles, (as well in my work i have no.of small circle making by using loop.) so i can't add the custom id to all, but i set the data to each circles.

Now how can i click on a required circle onclick to hide or animate other circle by data..?

I don't know the ways is correct. in case if this is not a way, let me know your advice, or give me some suggestion to do this.

thanks in advance.

```
var paper = new Raphael('myPaper',500,500);
var circle = paper.circle(100,100,100).attr({'fill':'red'});
var text = paper.text(100,100,"test Text").attr({'fill':'#fff'});

var smallCircle = paper.circle(300,100,50).attr({'fill':'green'}).data('id','green');

var newSet = paper.set();

newSet.push(circle,text);

newSet.attr({cursor:'pointer'}).data('id','oval');

newSet.click(function () {
    //smallCircle.attr({opacity:0.5}); //it works but i have no.of circle added by loop.
    smallCircle.data('green').attr({opacity:0.5}); //this is not working. i am setting unique data on each circle

} )
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amb9b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this... used the selector as follows..

```
smallCircle.data('id','green').attr({opacity:0.5}); //modified ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Amb9b/2/